# concurrent and conditional signal assignment (VHDL)

Tags: concurrency, vhdl

In VHDL, there are two types for signal assignment:

```
concurrent   ---->    when...else
             ---->    select...when...else

sequential   ---->    if...else
             ---->    case...when
```

Problem is that some say that `when...else` conditions are checked line by line (king of sequential) while `select...when...else` conditionals are checked once. See this [reference](http://quartushelp.altera.com/14.1/mergedProjects/hdl/vhdl/vhdl_pro_conditional_assign.htm) for example.

I say that `when..else` is also a sequential assignment because you are checking line by line. In other words, I say that there no need to say *if..else within a process is equivalent to when..else*. Why they assume `when..else` is a concurrent assignment?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: And why down vote?... I edited the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where you are hinting at in your problem has nothing to do with concurrent assignments or sequential statements.   It has more to do with the difference between if and case.   Before we get to that first lets understand a few equivalents.  The concurrent conditional assignment:

```
Y <= A when ASel = '1' else B when BSel = '1' else C ;
```

Is exactly equivalent to a process with the following code:

```
process(A, ASel, B, BSel, C) 
begin
  if ASel = '1' then
    Y <= A ;
  elsif BSel = '1' then 
    Y <= B ; 
  else 
    Y <= C ; 
  end if ;
end process ;
```

Likewise the concurrent selected assignment:

```
With MuxSel select
  Y <= A when "00", B when "01", C when others ;
```

Is equivalent to a process with the following:

```
process(MuxSel, A, B , C) 
begin
  case MuxSel is 
    when "00" =>    Y <= A; 
    when "01" =>    Y <= B ; 
    when others =>  Y <= C ;
  end case ; 
end process ;
```

From a coding perspective, the sequential forms above have a little more coding capability than the assignment form because case and if allow blocks of code, where the assignment form only assigns to one signal.   However other than that, they have the same language restrictions and produce the same hardware (as much as synthesis tools do that).   In addition for many simple hardware problems, the assignment form works well and is a concise capture of the problem.

So where your thoughts are leading really comes down to the difference between if and case.   If statements (and their equivalent conditional assignments) that have have multiple "elsif" in (or implied in) them tend to create priority logic or at least cascaded logic.   Where as case (and their equivalent selected assignments) tend to be well suited for things like multiplexers and their logic structure tends to be more of a balanced tree structure.

Sometimes tools will refactor an if statement to allow it to be equivalent to a case statement.   Also for some targets (particularly LUT based logic like Xilinx and Altera), the difference between them in terms of hardware effiency does not show up until there are enough "elsif" branches though.

With VHDL-2008, the assignment forms are also allowed in sequential code.  The transformation is the same except without the process wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Concurrent vs Sequential is about independence of execution.

A concurrent statement is simply a statement that is evaluated and/or executed independently of the code that surrounds it.  Processes are concurrent.  Component/Entity Instances are concurrent.   Signal assignments and procedure calls that are done in the architecture are concurrent.

Sequential statements (other than wait) run when the code around it also runs.

Interesting note, while a process is concurrent (because it runs independently of other processes and concurrent assignments), it contains sequential statements.

Often when we write RTL code, the processes that we write are simple enough that it is hard to see the sequential nature of them.   It really takes a statemachine or a testbench to see the true sequential nature of a process.

Comment: So please include this answer in the previous one. It is now clear